# CSS Mnemonics: How do you remember whether # or . is for class or id?

Tags: css, mnemonics

`#test` is the selector for `id="test"`

`.test` is the selector for `class="test"`

but how do *you* remember which way round they are (eg not .=id)

Comment: It's one of the most commonly used bits of CSS. You can learn through repetition. I don't need a mnemonic.

Comment: The same way how you remember that 2 comes after 1, and 3 comes after 2, etc. ... or that the past form of "do" is "did", ...

Comment: What these guys said. If you need a gimmick to remember this basic CSS syntax, you're probably not going to get very far in the software world. Sorry.

Comment: (In all seriousness, though, think of "Platform #3" or "Book #19" .. there's only one. It's an identifier, or "id".)

Comment: I'm pleased for you all that you can remember something. I wasn't asking for personal attacks, just a mnemonic. I don't spend enough time a year with CSS (thank god) to warrant committing this to my long-term memory. Finite capacity, and all.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about your memory having a finite capacity. While that might be true in theory, you have a *long* way to go before you reach it. (And I don't mean that to imply you're stupid; that's true of anyone! I learn all kinds of new things every day, and I'm nowhere near capacity.)

Comment: servermanfail, odds are a mnemonic is going to be longer and harder to remember that "dot class, pound id".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, in truth these things are so common that most people don't need mnemonics to remember them, but here's something I came up with, if it helps:

In terms of a filename a `.` and then an extension denotes a *type* of thing. There can be many different things of this type. With CSS, using classes you can denote a single style for many elements of the same *type*.

In terms of a URL, a `#` denotes an anchor link to a *specific* spot in the document. It refers to one location only. With CSS, using IDs you denote a single style for a single *specific* element.

Comment: Thanks, I will use yours. You answered both the questions.

Answer (score 6):

If a police officer catches you with "hash," he will ask to see your ID. If not you get to stay classy. It's really dumb, but that's how I remember.

Comment: I find the stupider something is the easier it is to remember. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

- Caller**ID** shows a phone **#**.
- Periods are round like pearls, and-- Pearls are **classy**.

(P.S.: What's with all the "you learn differently than me, so you suck" comments? Goodness. Repetition is OK for me, but if I can visualize something I pick things up more quickly. In fact, the [weirder something is the easier it is to memorize!](https://www.ted.com/talks/joshua_foer_feats_of_memory_anyone_can_do?language=en))

Comment: You really only need one good mnemoic: *CallerID shows a phone #* (nicely done, btw). `.` is just the other.

Comment: Strangely enough the . = pearl and pearls are classy has always worked better for me. But I'm a very visual learner. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

I learned it the same way I learned that quotes (rather than parentheses) are used for attributes' values — by typing them a couple of times.

If you or someone you know gets tripped up by `#` vs `.`, though, consider that many programming languages use a  `.` to access the members of an class-typed object.

Comment: Of course! *smacks head* I was stuck thinking that # was a channel - like a Twitter hash tag (goes to a group), or an IRC channel (group of people).

Answer (score 1):

I see I'm a day late (and maybe a dollar short), but I had the same problem in the early days and the following helped:
for the dot (.) as the selector for Class, I remembered it as: "My class always starts on the dot, not a minute early or late."
for the number sign (#) for ID, I just reminded myself that an ID(entification) card is incomplete without its number.

Answer (score 0):

Spend lots of time writing CSS. When you've got it wrong enough times, your brain will give in and retain it.

Comment: Thanks, would you like to pay me for spending lots of time writing CSS, as I do not enjoy it and limit myself in terms of minutes per year.